# How can I change the file's last modified date

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

How can I change the file's last modified date using the Document List Api?  Is this possible? Google Drive client somehow does it!

Comment: you cant. you trying to trick drive api?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [files.touch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/touch)

Set the file's updated time to the current server time.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/touch
```

Comment: This can only set it to the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Bu modifying a file content the last modified date should be changed automatically.

Are you having issues with this?

Comment: Perhaps they want to set it to a date in the past rather than the present date.

Answer (score 0):

use `touch` then you can change it